# Closed VisualState for ComboBox in Windows 10, animations not played

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-10, visualstatemanager, uwp

I have a problem with `Closed` VisualState for `ComboBox`. Animations in `Closed` state are being played only for the first time.

- ComboBox opened *for the first time* [all animations OK]
- ComboBox opened *for the second time* [no `Closed` animations]

Here's XAML I'm using:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
        <Storyboard>
            <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
         OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
         ClosedLength="0"
         OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />             
            <ColorAnimation To="Transparent"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="0"
                             Duration="0:0:0.2">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
        <Storyboard>
            <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
          OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
          ClosedLength="0"
          OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
            <ColorAnimation To="#66D3D3D3"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Background" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:0.2">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Could you give me some advise, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the default style have the same problem.

Comment: Did you extract this from the default style of the combobox?

Comment: Yes, snippet was extracted from default style. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used for this was to remove the `VisualState` for "Closed" from my Style. Once I had done this the `ComboBox` worked as expected.